# Getting Connection error while running AWS commands in powershell in windows 2012

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, powershell

We have installed AWS powershell tools with the given below version. When we try to run the AWS commands we get connection error as specified below:

```
---- AWS Powershell version---

PS C:\Users> Get-AWSPowerShellVersion
AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell
Version 2.3.8.1
Copyright 2012-2014 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

Amazon Web Services SDK for .NET
Version 2.3.8.1
Copyright 2009-2014 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

--- PSVersion    4.0 ------
```

.

```
--- Error ---

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not p
roperly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
2016-08-23 09:43:30,944 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

('Connection aborted.', error(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond a
fter a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

PS C:\Users> curl http://ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Port 80 and 443 are opened appropriately in the SGs. Tried with/without exporting the proxy in the machine.

Comment: Adding one more point. The windows machine is created with IAM role having full EC2 access.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved. 
We upgraded the AWS powershell version to 3.1.95.0.
Installed AWSToolsAndSDKForNet_sdk-3.1.95.0_ps-3.1.95.0_tk-1.10.0.2.
Set proxy using below:
Set-AWSProxy -Hostname <> -Port <>